# Combining layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

### Combining layout-large and layout-land

How can I make my app select a layout xml when the device is both large **and** in landscape?

I have the following directory structure;

```
res/layout/basic_layout.xml
res/layout-large/?
res/layout-land/?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create folders that are combinations of your required specification. For example you can combine large and landscape folders like so;

```
res/layout/basic_layout.xml                // Default layout
res/layout-large-land/basic_layout.xml     // Layout for when your on a screen 
                                           // that is at least large *and* landscape.
```

Note that your `layout-large-land` layouts will apply to xlarge screens in landscape if you have not also specified a `layout-xlarge-land` layout. The same can be said of any other combinations such as;

```
res/layout-small-port
```

Reference;

- [Android API - Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)